# want to open Link in external browser of WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, hyperlink, browser

The architecture is like:
On click of a button an HTML page opens which contains a link in it. On clicking the links I want to open it in external (default) browser of WP7 such that the application closes and link opens externally. How can I implement this?
Added this control in xaml file:

```
<phone:WebBrowser Name="browser" Margin="0,78,0,0" />
```

On button click:

```
   private void Information_Loaded(Object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

       using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("index_en.html"))
       {
           using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
           {
               string html = reader.ReadToEnd();

               browser.NavigateToString(html);                   
           }
       }
```

Now index_en.html has a link which is to be opened in external browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`WebBrowserTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.webbrowsertask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to launch the browser.

I've found that you need to escape the URL you pass to it though :(

Comment: How can i implement it by skipping?

Comment: @Shaireen: Implement *what* by skipping? Skipping what?

Comment: sorry for not making myself clear.Actually while using Web browser task i need to pass a url to it.So this url should be the name of html file? or is it the link that shud open?

Comment: @Shaireen: It's the address to open. The bit you'd put in the address bar in a browser.

Comment: Actually i have an Html file which opens on a button click.This file has the address to be opened in external browser.Now i want to capture click on that link ,only then i can open it externally?how to do that?

Comment: @Shaireen: So how are you displaying the file? If it's in a WebBrowser control, you should hook into the Navigating event - that will tell you the URL to load. You can then cancel navigation for the control and launch the browser task instead.

Comment: @Shaireen: No, I don't have VS handy to validate it... but I've given you enough suggestions already... and your question still isn't clear. Are you expecting the user to click on the link, or do you just want it opened immediately? If it's the latter, you'll need to find the link URL from the HTML yourself.

Comment: Expecting a user click on th link to open it

Comment: @Shaireen: In that case see an earlier comment - handle the Navigating event from the browser control.

Comment: Link have been moved http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.webbrowsertask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 12):

Normally, you would do so using `Target` property on `<a>` tag. But, in `WP7` (at least in Emulator), this does not work.

What you could do is intercept using `Navigating` event something like following:

```
void WebBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsSupposedToOpenInPhoneBrowser(e.Uri))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        WebBrowserTask task = new WebBrowserTask();
        task.URL = e.Uri.ToString();
        task.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: "IsSupposedToOpenInPhoneBrowser(e.Uri)"  property is not found.what does it signify?

Comment: It is just a fake method placeholder if you want to verify/filter Uris before opening them in phone browser... you can do without it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use something like that

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
    webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("http://www.someUrl.com");
    webBrowserTask.Show(); 
}
```