# WebBrowser Control Check Domain

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, browser

On Windows Phone, how can I check what domain someone has clicked on, and if it's not a certain domain, open IE instead?

Basically, if the user is on `http://m.google.com/app/plus` or any sub page, stay in the `webbrowser` control, but if it's something off site, preferably even if it's still on `http://m.google.com`, open in Internet Explorer.

I'm writing in C#, and please be specific, I'm insanely new to this.

EDIT: Also, is there a way to add a load bar to the WebBrowser control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `WebBrowser` XAML looks something like this:

`<phone:WebBrowser Name="browser_Post" Navigating="OnBrowserPostNavigating">`

Your event handler would look like this:

```
private void OnBrowserPostNavigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
{        
    // meaning the link is external, we want to open this outside of our app
    if (!e.Uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("m.google.com/app/plus"))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        WebBrowserTask task = new WebBrowserTask();
        task.URL = e.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
        task.Show();
    }
}
```

`e.Uri.AbsoluteUri` will be the absolute URI of the link being clicked, i.e., http://www.google.com. The `String.Contains()` is a simplistic way of checking the user's domain, but it should be sufficient.

The `WebBrowserTask` will open IE using the external URL, and all other links that are local to Google+ will stay within your local `WebBrowser`.

**Edit**
There is actually almost an identical question here:
[want to open Link in external browser of WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779363/want-to-open-link-in-external-browser-of-wp7)

Comment: I assume that you need `e.Cancel = true`

Comment: This looks promising, I'll be sure to try it when I get off work!

Comment: Just tried it, is there a way to do if contains this, or that? I guess I could do something with an else if. Hmm...I just set it to if google.com for now.

Comment: You could either do an `else if` or use the `||` operator to OR the conditions: `if (condition || condition2) { ... }`

Comment: @IvanBenko You are correct, I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Figured out how to use `||` in C#, but for some reason if I add that, it always opens a new window. Not sure why. Any ideas? The code is: `if (!e.Uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("m.google.com/app/plus") || !e.Uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("accounts.google.com"))`

Comment: That statement will always evaluate as `true`. You should wrap the whole statement in parenthesis and then apply the NOT operator to everything: `if (!(condition1 || condition2))`