# How to open browser window from vb.net on windows phone 7?

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, url

It's very simple question, but I couldn't find a solution for it. My application on VB.NET for Windows Phone 7 need to open some web links when user clicks the buttons.

Button clicked -> Internet Explorer application with link opens.

But how to make it? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [want to open Link in external browser of WP7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779363/want-to-open-link-in-external-browser-of-wp7)

Comment: Thanks, Olivier Payen! It works!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

1) Add the following statement to your code.

```
Imports Microsoft.Phone.Tasks
```

2) Add the following code to your application wherever you need it, such as in a button click event.

```
Dim webBrowserTask as WebBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask()
webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute)
webBrowserTask.Show()
```