# Open Web Browser from XAML app

Tags: c#, vb.net, xaml, windows-runtime

I would like to open the external webbrowser from my XAML app, similar to this: [want to open Link in external browser of WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779363/want-to-open-link-in-external-browser-of-wp7)

I can't seem to find the WebBrowserTask object:

```
Dim wbt As New WebBrowserTask()
wbt.Uri = New Uri("http://xxx.xxx.com/xxx.aspx")
wbt.Show()
```

Is there another way for WindowsRT/XAML?

Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(uri));
```

Comment: I might have missunderstood your question, but what about this in XAML <HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="{Binding Url}" DataContext="{Binding}" Content="Click me" TargetName="_blank"/>
(Win phone 8 XAML code- opens Url in IE in new window)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Launcher class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.aspx).

```
Dim uri As New Uri("http://www.bing.com")

Async Sub DefaultLaunch()

   ' Launch the URI
   Dim success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri)

   If success Then
      ' URI launched
   Else
      ' URI launch failed
   End If

End Sub
```