# open href link in a external browser in Windows Phone 7 apps

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

In my app we have a link in the index page. If i click the link i want to open in a browser on Windows Phone 7. I dont want to open that link inside the same apps browser, i want to open as a external browser/instance. Help me how to open external links in external browser WP7. FInd the below link which i am using to open my website.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Click</a>

<a href="http://www.gmail.com">Click</a>
```

If i click the above link it should be open in the external internet explorer. I am using Windows phone 7 with phonegap 2.2.0

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on [ChildBrowser plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/WindowsPhone/ChildBrowser) which allows you to open a new browser window:

1. Intercept click by adding onclick handler to link, for example onclick="openInExternalBrowser(this);return false;"
2. User openInExternalBrowser to call ChildBrowser plugin

> ```
> var url = ...
> ChildBrowser.install();
> window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(url);
> ```

3. If it works for you you can modify plugin .cs code to launch [`WebBrowserTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.webbrowsertask(v=vs.92).aspx) instead.

**Alternatively**

If you know what uri must be opened in external browser you can proceed with the following approach

```
> void WebBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e) {
>     if (IsSupposedToOpenInPhoneBrowser(e.Uri))
>     {
>         e.Cancel = true;
>         WebBrowserTask task = new WebBrowserTask();
>         task.URL = e.Uri.ToString();
>         task.Show();
>     } }
```

Src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4780213/255654